.NET 8.0 : change XML guid datatype before send
I have an application that's been written in .NET framework 4.0 and exposes some endpoints through WCF.
I wrote a .NET 8 application that will communicate with the application using .NET Core WCF Client but when I test creating an item it results in an error

Column requires a valid DataType

After investigating found that the Guid data type is System.Guid, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e and the System is expecting System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.
I'm looking for a way to change the Guid data type to the appropriate data type.
I have already tried the following:

change the Guid fields to string but returned that the column cannot be DBNull
changed targetted framework for the solution to ".NET Standard"


The Solution was to implement a custom Binding that implements IClientMessageInspector which provides a BeforeSendRequest function that reference the Message that will be sent to the endpoint.
In this Message object I was able to extract the body as XElement and modify the Guid Assembly full Name to the appropriate one which led to the endpoint to accept it.
Below is the code for the ClientMessageInspector
public class ClientMessageInspector : IEndpointBehavior, IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public ClientMessageInspector() { }

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {

        }

        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {

        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(this);
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {

        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            XmlDictionaryReader xmlDictionary = request.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
            XElement element = XElement.Load(xmlDictionary.ReadSubtree());
            element.ReplaceGuidDataType();
            request = Message.CreateMessage(request.Version,request.Headers.Action,element);
            return null;
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {

        }
    }

I hope this helps anyone who's searching for similar solution
